# Mouse events not read in C++ console

Tags: c++, winapi

When I move my mouse or do any mouse related operations like clicking, it isn't picked up or read by `ReadConsoleInput` while keyboard events are picked up.

It used to work but now, I don't know what's causing problems which blocks the reading of mouse events.

This is the code i'm using, and I referred from [This Website](http://www.benryves.com/tutorials/winconsole/3)

```
DWORD numEvents = 0;
DWORD numEventsRead = 0;
while (appIsRunning)
{
    reachedEnd = false;
    GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(Input_Handle, &numEvents);
    if (numEvents != 0)
    {
        INPUT_RECORD *eventBuffer = new INPUT_RECORD[numEvents];
        ReadConsoleInput(Input_Handle, eventBuffer, numEvents, &numEventsRead);
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < numEventsRead; ++i)
        {
            if (eventBuffer[i].EventType == KEY_EVENT) // this works
            {
                . // other 
                . // functions
                if (eventBuffer[i].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar == 'c' && eventBuffer[i].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
                    return true;
            }
            else if (eventBuffer[i].EventType == MOUSE_EVENT) // this doesnt work
            {
                cout << " E";
                if (eventBuffer[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
                {
                    char x[50];
                    fstream file;
                    file.open("test.txt", ios::out);
                    cout << " YY";
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(Output_Handle, { eventBuffer[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X , eventBuffer[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y });
                    cin >> x;
                    file << "SetConsoleCursorPosition(out, { "
                        << eventBuffer[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X << " , "
                        << eventBuffer[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y << "});   "
                        << x;

                }
            }
        }
        delete[] eventBuffer;
    }
    if (reachedEnd)
        return true;
}
```

I guess i should also post the code which sets the console mode and stuff

```
void initScr(COORD bufferSize, HANDLE& hOut, HANDLE& hIn, SMALL_RECT screen, SMALL_RECT side, Box& screenBox, Box& sideBox)
{
    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursorInfo;
    SMALL_RECT windowSize = { 0, 0, bufferSize.X - 1, bufferSize.Y - 1 };

    SetWindowPos(GetConsoleWindow(), HWND_TOPMOST, 5, 5, 0, 0, SWP_NOREDRAW | SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE);
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hOut, true, &windowSize);
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hOut, bufferSize);
    SetConsoleMode(hOut, ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_INSERT_MODE | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT);
    cls(hOut); //Clears the whole screen
    SetConsoleTitle(L"The Game");

    GetConsoleCursorInfo(hOut, &cursorInfo);
    cursorInfo.bVisible = false;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(hOut, &cursorInfo);

    screenBox.drawBox(screen, hOut, COLOR(bRed | bGreen | bBright ));
    sideBox.drawBox(side, hOut, COLOR(bRed | bGreen | bBright));
    setcursorPos({ 91, 5 }, hOut);
    cout << "Press \'C\' to re-create maze";
    setcursorPos({ 91, 7 }, hOut);
    cout << " Arrow keys for movement.";
    setcursorPos({ 0,0 }, hOut);
}
```

I guess this part of my code is quite messy.

Comment: Beware the memory leak.  There's not really a good reason for dynamic allocation here.

Comment: I suggest you add an `else` clause and see if you have some other event types sneaking in

Comment: Plus, you have sleeps and returns in the loop, you're not necessarily looking at every event.

Comment: @Ben Voight The returns are called when the player reaches the end and I doubt if that causes the problem. I tried running with only the mouse events' If statement and it still didnt work.

Comment: @BenVoigt Over event types comes in only when i resize and open the console. Also, is there any smoother better way for receiving input in C++ console? I know C++ console is bad in these situations, but I have no other choice.

Comment: You're setting `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_INSERT_MODE | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT` on the *screen buffer* handle, `hOut`. Obviously that fails, as it should, but you're not checking the return value of `SetConsoleMode` to see that it fails.

Comment: @eryksun Ahh, so thats where it got messed up. It works now, thanks. I was pretty confused about the way the func `SetConsoleMode` worked and kinda ignored it because it worked then.

Comment: @eryksun Is there any must-have parameters because i'm not sure if i'm using the SetConsoleMode function correctly. Right now, i've `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT`

Comment: You're not using window-input mode in the code you've show. Also, line-input mode is really only relevant with a cooked read (`ReadConsole`, `ReadFile`). Enabling extended flags is required to disable insert mode and quick-edit mode. Disabling the latter is required for getting mouse input, but you may want insert mode enabled. You may also want to enable processed input to get Ctrl+C console control events; otherwise only Ctrl+Break works.

Comment: IMO, you're changing the console settings so much that you should consider making it a GUI app that calls `AllocConsole` for a private console. Otherwise you should save all of the current settings at startup and restore them at shutdown. Of course if your program crashes or gets terminated, your shutdown code won't run, and the console will be left in this possibly unusable state.

Comment: @eryksun What do you mean by save all of the current settings? Right now I call the fuction InitScr whenever my program starts and I don't think i'll use AllocConsole for now. It's just a pet project for my highschool so I don't want to optimize it but rather keep it as a program that works pretty fine, and not near flawless-ish. I'll check out about AllocConsole if I have time though.

Comment: The console state at startup includes the window position, state, size, screen buffer size, cursor visibility, console input buffer and screen buffer modes, including insert mode and quick-edit mode. If your program is run from CMD it restores some of this state after it resumes, but not all of it, and definitely none of it will be restored from other programs such as calling your program from Python, etc. You've basically trashed the console. That's fine if it's yours to modify (`AllocConsole`), but ugly if you've inherited the console.

Comment: @eryksun I see, it'll most probably only be used in CMD but I'll modify the code so that it'll use `AllocConsole` so that I'll get bit more familiar with these stuff. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: @eryksun Oh and another question, I don't know if i have to create a new thread but when I get the input which checks whether they're holding or not, it takes some time to confirm it and it kinda messes with the smooth flow of movement of my 'hero' in the maze. Like if i hold up arrow, it moves one step up, waits around 250ms? not sure and then keeps moving up until i stop. So, is there any better way for receiving the Inputs or should I alter my if conditions and other things to make it smoother, probably something related to game theory? im not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is enabled selection by mouse in console.

just open your console `(Win + r) -> cmd`, open properties and disable highlighting function [image]

(I have russian language as my default, but checkbox that you need must be here (i highlighted it by red line))

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass the `ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT` flag to [`SetConsoleMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode).

Also notice that some functions will discard console mouse events.  Read the notes at the linked `SetConsoleMode` documentation.

Comment: I added the `ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT` and it doesn't seem to affect this. I'll look onto the functions which discard the mouse events.